# Python. Нестандартная фильтрация списка

Tags: python

Есть вот такой список строк, включая пустые:

```
lst = [
'* авто / ауто',
'! автомат .СеИ неод мI1 мнII1',
'автостоп 2 .СеИ неод мI1 мнII1 * устройство',
'! автомобиль 2 .СеИ неод мI3 мнI4',
'автостоп 3* .СеИ неод м!I1 * использование попутных машин',
'',
'антон .СеИ одуш м!I1 *??',
'! антон .СеИ одуш м!I1 *??',
'антонов .ПмИ III1',
'антонов .ПмИ IIIф о',
'',
'аукцион .СеИ неод мI1 мнII1 * <= augere',
'! август .СеИ одуш м!I1',
'август .СеИ одуш м!I1',
'! август .СеИ неод мI1 мнII1',
'август .СеИ неод мI1 мнII1',
]
```

То есть список строк делится на группы. Группы разделены пустой строкой.

Как по-быстрому удалить только первые строки из каждой группы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = [a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if a[i-1] != ''][1:]
```

Comment: Сенкс. Всё правильно, за исключением первого элемента из первой группы. Он не удаляется в этом коде.

Comment: Тогда вручную удалить его, `x = x[1:]`. Поправил

Comment: Можно ещё так: `if i and a[i-1]`

Comment: @CrazyElf, а интересно что быстрее было бы в процессорном времени, делать две проверки на `i` и `a[i-1]` или все же скопировать массив `[1:]`

Comment: Думаю, копирование всегда медленнее ))  Если бы это было не копирование, а view, тогда другое дело.

Comment: Кстати, будет по разному работать, в зависимости от того, есть ли в конце списка пустая строка, или нет. Или есть ли две пустые строки подряд.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю альтернативный вариант. Очень люблю варианты перебора и сравнения соседних элементов через `zip`, без использования индексов. Это не самый оптимальный вариант когда данных много, потому что создаётся лишняя копия списка (правда, это вроде можно при желании обойти, используя итератор):

```
lst1 = [curr for prev, curr in zip(lst, lst[1:]) if prev]
```

Comment: Очень интересный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё один вариант:

```
flag = False
out_list = [x for x in in_list if (flag, flag := x)[0]]
```